# Optimize lots of queries

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance

I have a list of upwards 3,000 decimal values and for each one I need to lookup another decimal value from a SQL Server database. Currently I'm using the .Net `SqlClient` classes.
Making 3,000 queries seems inefficient, but I'm not sure if there's a neat efficient way of combining the queries into few calls.

The lookup table currently contains about 1,500,000 values and I don't want to retrieve any values from the database except those that actually needs to be looked up (so I can't cache the whole table in memory etc).

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008, you could pass in a Table Valued Parameter to your query - pass in a table of values, to then join on to in your query. Example with performance comparisons against alternative approaches (CSV & XML): http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html

I'd see how that performs and go from there.

If you're not using SQL Server 2008, you could try the alternative approaches compared in that article (XML then CSV) - there's plenty of discussions too on "how to pass multiple values to a sproc" here on StackOverflow. Or, bulk load the decimal values to a temp table and then join on that.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 introduced [table value parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). You can [define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) them as user type parameters and pass them through to stored procedures and UDFs (with UDFs they need to be read only).

You can write a stored procedure that takes a table of decimals, does the lookup and returns the data you need, all in one query.

Answer (score 0):

If the values do not change that often, make a AppFabric distributed cache bevore it.
that would be the best way to speed it up.
in my opinion, moving the logic to stored procedures is normally not the best way for scalability.